# Show figures when a dropdown option is selected - javascript

Tags: javascript, function, calculator, dropdown

I am making a car loan calculator and this is what it is ment to do:

- in the text box you enter the amount you would like to borrow.
- in the dropdown box you select a loan term. Each year represents a
  repayment APR so example if you want to borrow over 3 years the rate
  is 32.50%
- the result is then displayed for the monthly repayment and then total repayment.

I am trying to figure out a way to display the total repayment. I want to know is there a way that when i select for example the loan term at 4 years it will hide the other total repayment options? and vice versa. At the moment it displays all the total repayments.

My HTML

```
<!-- main body -->
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
        <form class="credit">
          <div class="form-group">

          <!-- amount to borow -->
            <label for="amount">Amount To Borrow</label>
              <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-addon">EUR</div>
              <input id="amount" type="number" min="1" max="1000000" onchange="computeLoan()" class="form-control validate" id="amount" placeholder="Enter amount" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- End amount to borrow -->

    <!-- dropdown -->
    <div class="dropdown">
        <select id= "rate" onchange="computeLoan()">
            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select A Loan Term</option>
            <span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <option value="46.64">2 Years @ 46.64%</option>
            <option value="32.50">3 Years @ 32.50%</option>
            <option value="26.08">4 Years @ 26.08%</option>
            <option value="22.00">5 Years @ 22.00%</option>
          </ul>
        </select>
        </div>
        <!-- end dropdown -->
<br>


<!-- display the results -->
<h3 id="monthlyPayment"></h3>
<h4 id="totalPayment"></h4>
<!-- end display results -->

<h4 id="threeYears"></h4>
<h4 id="fourYears"></h4>
<h4 id="fiveYears"></h4>

</div>
</div>
</form>

<!-- end form  -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

My Javascript

```
// conditional logic
function computeLoan()

{


    // grab the selected value of the dropdown box 
    var r = document.getElementById("rate");
    var rateSelected = parseFloat(r.value); 

    //grab elements by their ID
    var amount = parseFloat(document.getElementById('amount').value);

    //do the maths do find the percentage
    var interest = (amount * (rateSelected * .01))


  //Monthly payment
  var monthlyPayment = ((amount / 1000 ) * rateSelected).toFixed(2);
  monthlyPayment = monthlyPayment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

   // total payment
  var totalPayment = (monthlyPayment * 24).toFixed(2);
  totalPayment = totalPayment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

   var threeYears = (monthlyPayment * 36).toFixed(2);
  totalPayment = totalPayment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

   var fourYears = (monthlyPayment * 48).toFixed(2);
  totalPayment = totalPayment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");

  var fiveYears = (monthlyPayment * 60).toFixed(2);
  totalPayment = totalPayment.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");


     // display the results
    document.getElementById('monthlyPayment').innerHTML = "Monthly Repayment: &euro;"+monthlyPayment;
    document.getElementById('totalPayment').innerHTML = "Total Repayment for 2 Years: &euro;"+totalPayment;

    document.getElementById('threeYears').innerHTML = "Total Repayment for 3 Years: &euro;"+threeYears;
    document.getElementById('fourYears').innerHTML = "Total Repayment for 4 Years: &euro;"+fourYears;
    document.getElementById('fiveYears').innerHTML = "Total Repayment for 5 Years: &euro;"+fiveYears;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to react to the `change` event of the `<select>` and hide or show the desired element either by changing their `.style.display` property to `node` or `block` or `inline-block`.